# Salesforce 1 guidelines for App Icon and Action Icon - how to set background colour?

Tags: salesforce1-app

1. The Icon Guidelines say (for Navigation Menu App Icon)
   "Within Setup, set the background colour to match the colour in your icon file"  Are they referring to the colour palette when creating you own Tab?  And if so, is there any way to define the exact colour as the palette is limited?
2. If you use the Publisher Action Icon guidelines for an Action on the Action bar,  the icon figure shrinks, and for a VisualForce action, the background is set to purple.  Any way to change this colour?